# Writing state $ |\Psi⟩ =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|00⟩+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|01⟩$ as separate qubits (qiskit textbook)

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, mathematics, textbook-and-exercises, linear-algebra

While going through the IBM qiskit textbook online, I came across the following question in section 2.2:

Write the state: $ |\Psi⟩ =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|00⟩+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|01⟩$ as two separate qubits.

I understand tensor products with qubits, but I don't know how to even begin this problem. Does anyone have some advice on how to separate a state into its constituent qubits?

Answer (score 7):

As is the case with ordinary multiplication, tensor product distributes over addition, so we can pull $|0\rangle$ on the first qubit out in front

$$
\begin{align}
|\Psi⟩ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\color{red}{0}0\rangle+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|\color{red}{0}1\rangle \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\color{red}{|0\rangle}\otimes|0\rangle+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\color{red}{|0\rangle}\otimes|1\rangle \\
&= \color{red}{|0\rangle}\otimes\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle\right) \\
&= \color{red}{|0\rangle}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle\right)
\end{align}
$$

and what remains in parenthesis is the state of the second qubit.

Note that people generally tend to make [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) signs $\otimes$ implicit. I marked them explicitly to highlight the [distributive law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) familiar from ordinary multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Giving $|\psi \rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|00\rangle + \dfrac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|01\rangle$ we can see that the first qubit is in the state $|0\rangle$ so we can rewrite the state $|\psi\rangle$ as a tensor product:

$$ |\psi \rangle = |0\rangle \otimes \bigg( \dfrac{|0\rangle + i|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)$$

So the first qubit is in the state $|0\rangle$ and the second qubit is in the state $\dfrac{|0\rangle + i|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Other important methods to check if a state is a separable or entangled are the Peres-Horodecki criterion and Schmidt decomposition.

Comment: Could you please the derivation for this decomposition.