# Qiskit textbook - exercise 2.2 - why doesn't the correct answer give the same statevector?

Tags: qiskit, textbook-and-exercises

In the Qiskit textbook, I'm stuck on one of the exercises in section 2.2.  The question is:

Write the state: [image]as two separate qubits.

The answer has already been covered in [this question here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15477/writing-state-psi-frac1-sqrt200-fraci-sqrt201-as-separa), and is defined as:

[image]

This makes sense to me - we're basically factoring out the first qubit.
However, for my own benefit, I tried multiplying out the vectors and I get different results:

Using the original form:

[image]

Using the answer supplied:

[image]

Why don't these give the same values?

*n.b. Apologies for the use of images - I only had MS Word at my disposal and couldn't find an easy way to export the equations bar screen-shotting.*

Comment: You do not need additional software to write mathematics on this site, for a quick overview of how to do this please see [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks - I already had the equations in Word, so I was trying (unsuccessfully) to convert them without downloading any other tools.  Next time, I'll start by writing them directly in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your answer you are treating $|xy\rangle$ as a direct sum of vectors $|x\rangle$ and $|y\rangle$. However, $|xy\rangle = |x\rangle \otimes |y\rangle$ is actually shorthand for the tensor (Kronecker) product of $|x\rangle$ and $|y\rangle$ (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)  for more details on the Kronecker product).

In particular if $|x\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$ and $|y\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} c \\ d \end{pmatrix}$ then
$$
|xy\rangle = |x\rangle\otimes |y\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} ac \\ ad \\ bc \\ bd \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Right - so my error is in the first vector calculation and both should be 1/(√2) [1 i 0 0] ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by both. 
$$
|00\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$ 
and
$$
|01\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}   = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} 
$$

Comment: By "both", I meant the vector of the factorised answer and the vector from the original question.  I think *both* should have come out as $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)} \begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ i \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Ok, yeah, exactly!